# Cumulative Sum of values of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as below

```
    Date            Value  
    ----------      -----  
    02-04-2017      20  
    04-04-2017      10  
    09-04-2017      15  
    14-04-2017      8  
    25-04-2017      3   
    28-04-2017      2  
    02-05-2017      5
```

Expected output:

```
    WeeklyDate   WeeklyValue  
    -----------  ------------   
    01-04-2017   0  
    08-04-2017   30  
    15-04-2017   53  
    22-04-2017   53  
    29-04-2017   58  
    06-05-2017   63
```

I want the output with dates with 7 days interval starting from 1st of the month and cumulative sum of values.

Kindly help!!

Comment: What have you tried? What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: Why are your date strings all mixed up? You need to be using ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD format. It is not clear what you expect because your dates are ambiguous.

Comment: It helps if you can show your attempts to resolve this. This is not a 'please write this code for me' formum

Comment: Is your first date February 4th or April 2nd?

Comment: @SeanLange it is April 2nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
;WITH Tally AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.n) AS n
   FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS t1(n)
   CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS t2(n)
)
SELECT x.d AS WeeklyDate, COALESCE(z.running_total, 0) AS WeeklyValue  
FROM Tally AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD (DAY, (t.n - 1) * 7, '2017-04-01')) AS x(d)  
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT SUM(Value) AS running_total
   FROM mytable
   WHERE [Date] <= x.d) AS z
```

The query uses a *tally table* created by a `CTE`. It is large enough to accommodate more than the week number of a whole year.

Using the numbers of the tally table, a `CROSS APPLY` operation calculates the weekly date value up to which the running total is calculated.

The `OUTER APPLY` performs a `SUM` aggregation to obtain the actual value of the running total.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eacac/2)